# Ansible: read value of become option in playbook

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to get value of parameter `--become` in a playbook?
For example, if the flag `--become` is present, I expect to get `true`, and `false` otherwise.

I used to think that there was a `become` variable, but actually it is absent.

Ideally, I want to use something like:

```yaml
- name 
  become: {{ become }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your example makes any sense. The default behavior, if you specify `--become` on the command line, is pretty much exactly what you show in your example: all tasks will behave as if they have `become: true`.

Comment: Really I want to do something like that: if some variable is true, then set become to no.
In other cases don't set become (use default behavior)
I use no something like that:
become: {{var | default(omit)}}
But omit unset become at all. And If I set --become parameter and var is absent it really don't escalate privileges

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: get UID
      become: "{{ myvar|default(false)|bool }}"
      command: id
      register: uid

    - debug:
        var: uid.stdout
```

If we run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

We get:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "uid.stdout": "uid=1000(lars) gid=1000(lars) ..."
}
```

Whereas if we set `myvar=true`:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e myvar=true
```

We get:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "uid.stdout": "uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023"
}
```

---

We use `myvar|default(false)|bool` so that if `myvar` isn't set, we get the boolean value `false`, and if `myvar` is set to the string value "false", the `bool` filter turns that into `false`, because otherwise a non-empty string evaluates to `true` in a boolean context.